# How to get hex value or rgb value of the color from getColorFilter in android

Tags: android

I have an `ImageView` in my layout. I set a color to that Image using `setColorFilter()`. Now I am trying to get the same color using `getColorFilter()`. But its returning a `ColorFilter` object. How can I extract hex color from it.

**This is the way I am trying to set color to the Image:**

```
image.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#ECECEC"), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Now I am using below code which is returning a `ColorFilter` object:

```
image.getColorFilter()
```

**But how to get hex value or RGB value of the color from it ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the method to get the color is hidden for reasons best known to google:

```
/**
 * Returns the ARGB color used to tint the source pixels when this filter
 * is applied.
 *
 * @see Color
 * @see #setColor(int)
 *
 * @hide
 */
public int getColor() {
    return mColor;
}
```

You can use a variable to store that:

```
int colorFilterColor ;
```

and While setting colorFilter:

```
int color = Color.parseColor("#ECECEC");
image.setColorFilter(color , PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
colorFilterColor  = color ;
```

For getting color:

```
public int getFilterColor(){
return colorFilterColor ;
}
```

Comment: This is a good idea. But Why `getColorFilter()` is not returning color values? just wanted to know.

Comment: @Hiren i checked the source of PorterDuffColorFilter it seems the method to get color is hidden

Comment: this is really bad :( @Coldfire